# OAuth2 Session - How to add multiple scopes?

Tags: scopes, authlib

I am trying to add multiple scopes but it seems instead of adding spaces in the url, it adds +. I'm not sure how to ensure a space is added. I'm storing the scopes in a list.

```
CALLBACK_URL = 'https://localhost/callback'
CLIENT_SECRET = SETTINGS['client_secret']
CLIENT_SCOPES = ['esi-mail.organize_mail.v1 ', 'esi-mail.send_mail.v1 ', 'esi-assets.read_assets.v1 ',
                 'esi-characters.read_blueprints.v1 ', 'esi-assets.read_corporation_assets.v1 ',
                 'esi-corporations.read_blueprints.v1 ']
ENDPOINT = 'https://login.eveonline.com/oauth/authorize'


def oauth_session(client_id, client_secret, scopes):
    client = OAuth2Session(client_id, client_secret, scope=scopes)
    uri, state = client.create_authorization_url(ENDPOINT)
    return uri, state
```

The response shows the following as scopes (just scopes for brevity):

```
&scope=esi-mail.organize_mail.v1++esi-mail.send_mail.v1++esi-assets.read_assets.v1++esi-characters.read_blueprints.v1++esi-assets.read_corporation_assets.v1++esi-corporations.read_blueprints.v1+
```

Am I using the wrong data structure, or there is something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was not the format of the scope at all - I was missing a redirect_uri that was required for the API I am using.